# Discord RPC C#. Не работает Timestamps

Tags: c#, winforms, discord

Всем привет, пытаюсь отобразить в дискорд оставшееся время до окончания проигрывания песни, отправляю число, но не работает, якобы 0:00. Думал, что может проблема в скобках TimeSpan.FromSecond, решил подставить число 100. Работает. Решил проверить отправку числа в текстбокс, отображается, тогда что не так в моем коде?

```
try {
    //Set the rich presence
    //Call this as many times as you want and anywhere in your code.
    client.SetPresence(new RichPresence()
    {
        Details =  audio.Artist,
        State = audio.Title,
        Assets = new Assets()
        {
            LargeImageKey = "vk_logo",
            LargeImageText = "Cлушает в VK Player",
            SmallImageKey = ""
        },

        Timestamps = new Timestamps()
        {
            Start = DateTime.UtcNow,
            End = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(endtime),
        },
    }) ; 
}
catch
{

}

private void SetEndTime(object Object, EventArgs e)
{
    int Seconds = (int)Player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    DurationSlider.Maximum = Seconds;
    int Minutes = Seconds / 60;
    int MinutedDS = Seconds;
    Seconds -= Minutes * 60;
    string strSeconds = $"{Seconds}";
    if (Seconds < 10)
    {
        strSeconds = $"0{Seconds}";
    }
    string EndTime = $"{Minutes}:{strSeconds}";
    TimeEndInfoLabel.Text = EndTime;
    endtime = MinutedDS + Seconds;
}

public double endtime;
```

Comment: Выведите на экран/в консоль дебага эти два значения (`Start` и `End`) и посмотрите, что не так. Ну а еще лучше, научитесь пользоваться отладкой, поставьте точку остановки в нужное место (или `Debug.Break();` в коде), запустите под отладкой, ну и далее `F10`/`F11` (с заходом в метод) перемещайтесь по коду, смотря какие значения там есть и соответствуют они вашим ожиданиям или нет.

Comment: Никогда не пишите пустые блоки catch на неизвестные исключения! Наверняка же там какая-то ошибка случилась, а вы и не знаете.

Comment: Ну и вычисления у вас крайне странные, у вас же есть `Player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan`, зачем переводить его сначала в секунды (да ещё и так странно), а потом обратно? Сразу бы и сохранили в поле. Опять же, в строку можно перевести его тоже довольно просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, кто помогал, решил этот вопрос таким решением.

```
try {
    //Set the rich presence
    //Call this as many times as you want and anywhere in your code.
    client.SetPresence(new RichPresence()
    {
        Details =  audio.Artist,
        State = audio.Title,
        Assets = new Assets()
        {
            LargeImageKey = "vk_logo",
            LargeImageText = "Cлушает в VK Player",
            SmallImageKey = ""
        },

        Timestamps = new Timestamps()
        {
            Start = DateTime.UtcNow,
            End = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(audio.Duration),
        },
    }) ; 
}
catch
{

}
```